# Menus not visible in Appearance after being registered

Tags: menus, wp-admin

The menus have been registered in `functions.php`, but they don't appear within the Appearance > Menus section in Admin and the pages, posts etc options are greyed out.

The menus are saved, as you can not create the menu with the same name again.

[image: Greyed out Menu options]

Within `functions.php`:

```
function theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'search-form' ) );
    /*** Register Menus */
    if (function_exists('register_nav_menus'))
    {
        register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'main-menu'         => __( 'Main Menu', 'site' ),
            'footer-menu'       => __( 'Footer Menu', 'site' ),
            )
        );
    }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup');
```

Within `header.php`

```
wp_nav_menu(
                array(
                    'menu'          => 'Main Menu',
                    'container'     => '',
                    'depth'         => 1,
                    'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
                )
            );
```

Within `footer.php`

```
wp_nav_menu(
                array(
                    'menu'          => 'Footer Menu',
                    'container'     => '',
                    'items_wrap'    => '',
                    'theme_location' => 'footer-menu'
                )
            );
```

The main issue here is that these menus exist and are rendering out on the site, but they seem to be hidden within the admin panel and if a new menu is created it never shows up.

Using Wordpress version 4.7 (Latest)

Plugins:
[image: Current plugins]

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your `theme_setup()` function in your `functions.php` file.

The error you get simply points out the fact that the menu name ***Main Menu*** already exists.

In other to resolve this you should replace your *Main Menu* menu name definitions in your `functions.php` file with something other than what it currently is.

*It's possible you might be using a theme or a plugin which already has a menu name registered as such, accounting for the current menu name conflict.*

---

Update:

Your code works well. I think your challenge has to do with registered *menu location* **vs** actual *menu (form the dashboard, as actual menus to be rendered into a given registered menu location)*.

What you should do: type inside the "Menu Name" input box as seen on you first shared screenshot a new menu name, then, click on the "Create Menu" button; your custom registered menu locations will then be visible as seen in the screenshot below:

[image: Newly created menu (stacktest)]

Comment: Thank you, further to this - the menus exist and are rendering out on the site, but they seem to be hidden within the admin panel and if a new menu is created it never shows up. I don't believe there are any plugins which have menu conflicts.

Comment: Noted @mixchex; you may consider updating the OP with that detail so as to clarify further the nature of the challenge you are facing. BTW: what is the outcome when using a menu name and definition other than the current *Main Menu* in your `theme_setup()` function?

Comment: Thank you @nyedidikeke. The information has been added. I have changed both name definitions and this has no difference unfortunately.

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using? Are you editing a WordPress theme from the WordPress Directory, a commercial or a custom one? What are the current active plugin you have on your WordPress installation instance?

Comment: OP updated. Wordpress 4.7 and plugins screenshot added.

Comment: @mixchex: Just updated my post above to illustrate how you can get your registered menu locations showing on your dashboard.

Comment: this would be the case as standard, but there is something more conflicting which is hiding every menu which is created. Also there is not a 'Manage Locations' tab either.

Comment: Very strange @mixchex. I got no answers to these questions: * Are you editing a WordPress theme from the WordPress Directory, a commercial or a custom one?*

Comment: It's a custom theme, so I think there is a conflict. I will update when I resolve. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @mixchex: any progress?

Comment: yes, thank you - it took a while to figure the cause of this plroblem - the WPCoreSys plugin. Thank you for your help. Answer added.

Comment: You can then mark my answer as such @mixchex.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

The issue was caused by the WPCoreSys plugin. Not sure of its purpose.

Something which was in the plugin had a conflict and stopped the menu editor from working.

The plugin was not visible within the Plugins section, but it was present within the file directory. As it was not active, it was removed and now the menu area functions as expected.

Comment: FYI, this is a virus/backdoor. You were hacked. It adds other backdoors so that even if you deleted this the hacker could get back in whenever they like again. Just dealing with this for someone now. It modifies core WP files, theme files like you header.php and tracks stuff in the DB. On the site I was looking at they'd managed to changed the admin login and other users passwords. I'm lucky that I can blow away the site and it's not too bad to start from scratch, but otherwise it's a pretty manual cleanup. More info: https://sarn.phamornsuwana.com/wpcoresys-dolly-hack/